# Not able to log enough information for azure table storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have a table in the azure storage account. When I changed the table values from the azure portal UI, I get log events But they are only titled 'List storage account keys'. I do not get enough information from it, Like if it edits or creates operation, or changes history. So how can I get this type of information in the log? I also try logging from classic monitoring. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-log-format from this documentation I found only limited information, But I do not get 'account-name' or change-history there.   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You must activate the Log Analytics in your storage account, as you say the Activity log is too general, this is because the Activity Log is oriented to the resource (Storage Account)

To activate the Log, follow this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/manage-storage-analytics-logs?tabs=azure-portal#enable-logs

And here you'll have more information about monitoring Azure Table storage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/monitor-table-storage?tabs=azure-portal

Hope this helps!

Comment: I already activated the Log analytics. Here I get different log information than the activity log. But here I do not get any change history or property that will be updated. And another problem here I do not find any account owner information about who triggered the event. Is there any way to get this information?